# Android PhoneGap get yaw, pitch, roll, relative to earth coordinates

Tags: android, cordova, webview, orientation, sensors

I have the following script in a web page:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {

    // Get Euler angles from device
    var alpha = 360 - event.alpha;
    var beta = event.beta;
    var gamma = event.gamma;

    // Display Euler angles
    document.getElementById("alpha").innerHTML = alpha;
    document.getElementById("beta").innerHTML = beta;
    document.getElementById("gamma").innerHTML = gamma;

}, false);
```

This works great in a browser such as mobile Firefox for Android. It displays my heading, pitch, and roll, relative to Earth coordinates (alpha is always 0 when pointing north, beta is always 90 when holding device vertical, etc).

Now I load the same script into a PhoneGap app using WebView, and it displays nothing.  How do I get these values in PhoneGap without having to completely re-invent sensor fusion from scratch?